# Can't connect to the internet in Ubuntu 16.04 (Virtualbox)

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox

I'm a newbie on Ubuntu and I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Virtualbox.

I can't connect to the internet in the virtual machine.

My Network Settings Are:

- Network 1 = NAT
- Network 2 = Bridge Network Adapter

I also have enabled the option **VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter In Host Machine**.

I still can't connect to the internet.

Also I get `enp0s3` and `enp0s8` instead of `eht0` and `eht1` after running `ip link`.

Can anybody help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you have 2 NICs on the VM? If both are configured with default routes I would assume the guest would not know the best route out of it's LAN.

Could I suggest that you remove the bridged NIC and leave the NAT one in place. Confirm that the guest VM has a good `ifconfig`, with a ping positive default route and good DNS servers (try `dig` www.bbc.co.uk from terminal and see if it resolves) then try the web again.